# creating package with setuptools not installing properly

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I'm using setuptools to try and create a module for python.

I have tried installing locally and from git with pip (version 3.5). pip says that the package is installed and it is listed in the installed packages with "pip list" and "pip freeze". When I try to import the module in my script I get an import error "ImportError: No module named 'jackedCodeTimerPY' ". I've been banging my head on the wall for a while now and I think that is a really simple problem and I'm just missing something.

You can find my repo at https://github.com/BebeSparkelSparkel/jackedCodeTimerPY

My setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='jackedCodeTimerPY',
      version='0.0.0',
      license='MIT',
      description='Simple but powerful code timer that can measure execution time of one line, functions, imports and gives statistics (min/max/mean/total time, number of executions).',
      author='William Rusnack',
      author_email='williamrusnack@gmail.com',
      url='https://github.com/BebeSparkelSparkel/jackedCodeTimerPY',
      classifiers=['Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha', 'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'],
      py_modules=["jackedCodeTimerPY"],
      install_requires=['tabulate==0.7.5'],
     )
```

My directory looks like this:

```
LICENSE.md      jackedCodeTimerPY.py
README.md     jackedCodeTimerPY.pyc
__pycache__     setup.py
build       small.jpg
dist        t2.py
example.py      tests.py
jackedCodeTimerPY.egg-info
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

```
pip3 install git+git://github.com/BebeSparkelSparkel/jackedCodeTimerPY.git@master

Cloning git://github.com/BebeSparkelSparkel/jackedCodeTimerPY.git (to master) to /tmp/pip-lq07iup9-build
Collecting tabulate==0.7.5 (from jackedCodeTimerPY==0.0.0)
  Downloading tabulate-0.7.5.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: tabulate, jackedCodeTimerPY
  Running setup.py install for tabulate ... done
  Running setup.py install for jackedCodeTimerPY ... done
Successfully installed jackedCodeTimerPY-0.0.0 tabulate-0.7.5

python3 -c 'from jackedCodeTimerPY import JackedTiming; print(JackedTiming)'

<class 'jackedCodeTimerPY.JackedTiming'>
```

Comment: By the way, take a look at [`time.perf_counter()`](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/08/python-clocks-explained/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's more of demo project. There must be something wrong elsewhere now, because I had been installing fine for me before.